# XSD to C# multiple defined types Ambiguity

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd2code

I have been given multiple large XSD's that redundantly define the same types. The end game i'm going for is to be able to generate C# classes from these XSD's with the same(ONE) namespace while not having hundreds of 'namespace already contains a definition for' errors.

**Is there an automated way/program to extract the redundant types and put them in a separate XSD to include in the individual files?**

I have tried to use xsd.exe to generate one .cs file.

1. I'm not sure if this tries to compare the types for uniqueness or just fails on previously defined types.
2. This does not "automagically" create serialization methods for all objects generated like XSD2code

I have used xsd2code to generate the .cs files but it only accepts one file at a time and I am having to generate each file in a separate namespace.

I am trying to save time and my mind but If I have to do it by hand each time a new version of the xsd's comes out(hopefully not too often) then so be it.